# How to put an modal at the absolute front of a page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a modal image. I have a sticky side bar that shares a grid with the main content. It's a fixed image so i can scroll it separate from the main content.

I add a div by JavaScript that has an image I want to show as a modal. It can't cover the main content as it gets covered if I set it to fixed and it goes after the main content if i set it to absolute.

I have tried to delete all the css besides the modal and position in as fixed. It still hides behind the rest of the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content = "utf-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css"> 
    <title>
        Images
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div>
                <ul id="foldersList">
                </ul>

            </div>
                <div id = imageDisplay>
                <!--I add a grid of thumnail images here if that affects anything-->
            </div>
    </div>
<div class="canvas"><!--This is added through javascript and what I want to put in the front-->
    <img src=""/>
</body>

<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="imageLoader.js">

</script>

</html>
```

If i put the canvas to `position: fixed` it always goes to the top of the page but behind everything else. How can i bring it to the front? This is the css i think is mostly relevant:

```css
    *{
        margin: 0;
    }

    .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
    }
    #foldersList {
        position: fixed;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #5f8c4a;
        height:100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        left: 0;
    }

    .canvas {
         float: left;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.7);
    }


    .currentImage {
        max-width: 95%;
        max-height: 95%;
        margin:auto;
        display:block;
    }

    #foldersList > li{
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #foldersList > li:hover:not(.active){
        background-color: #224021;
        color: white;
    } 


    #imageDisplay {
        background-color: #35402D;
        display: inline-grid;
        position: relative;
        grid-column-start: 2; 
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .imagePreview{
        height: 200px;
        transition: ease-in .2s;
        margin: 20px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    }

    #imageDisplay {
        background-color: #35402D;
        display: inline-grid;
        grid-column-start: 2; 
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `z-index` larger may solve your problem.

```
.canvas {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't affect it. It will still just hide behind the other elements

Comment: Do you have an online working example to reproduce your problem? Your code include some css and js files that may cause the problem.

Comment: No this is only ran on a local machine. I did manage to fix the issue by using `position: fixed`. I don't know why this combination works however as it was the opposite when the sidebar was absolute and the modal was fixed.

Comment: Its not the position change, I used `top:0` and `left:0`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. I added these to .canvas:

```css
    .canvas{
        top: 0; <!--This was added-->
        left: 0; <!--This was also added-->
        float: left;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.7);
        position: absolute|fixed; <!--Both work now-->
    }
```